# How to open appStore from web link?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm able to open my appStore page a click event on a UIButton that has an IBAction associated, similar this:

```
- (IBAction) BuyFullAlbum {
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=...";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

It works fine.
Now I need to upgrade my app, and I downloaded a post from a wordpress blog via rss and I want to display the post in a UIWebView. I can show the correct html from the post into the UIWebView, but now I decide to link the appStore to a webLink posted inside a webpage.

Why if I click on the link in the UIWebView, it opens the page of the app's review in the appStore and not the directly link to the appStore?
Is this a way to go directly from a link in a web page to the appStore link of an app?

Answer (score 7):

http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker is this what your looking for? You can get the direct link once you find your app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your link in the HTML is wrong. I has to be in a particular format to start up the app store app. I'd definitely use the linkmaker suggested by thyrgle. If you need more info the [Apple URL Scheme Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iTunesLinks/iTunesLinks.html) is helpful too.